# How to check oracle error description in sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to find the oracle error's description in SQL*PLUS.  Similar command in DB2 as

```
? SQLXXXX
```

Where `XXXX` is the error number.

Comment: we have a new CLI, SQLcl. We have error message lookup built into the tool, you can simply run OERR in the program, and no need to install an Oracle client http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use oerr utility.

**Example:**

```
[oracle@ora12c Desktop]$ oerr ora 01950
01950, 00000, "no privileges on tablespace '%s'"
Cause:    User does not have privileges to allocate an extent in the
          specified tablespace.

Action:   Grant the user the appropriate system privileges or grant the user
          space resource on the tablespace.
```

You can search error code on this webpage [Search for Error Messages](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db92/db92.error_search?prefill=ORA-) or you can download the Database Error Messages documentation from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/toc.htm).

Note: This utility is not available on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i'm using Windows OS.So there is no utility for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend an exclamation mark `!` in SQL*Plus to any shell command which will allow you to execute the command without leaving SQL*Plus:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> !oerr ora 01950
01950, 00000, "no privileges on tablespace '%s'"
// *Cause:  User does not have privileges to allocate an extent in the
//          specified tablespace.
// *Action: Grant the user the appropriate system privileges or grant the user
//          space resource on the tablespace.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for Windows, i can only remember calling the the SQLERRM function.
Something like this: `BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQLERRM(-6511): ' || TO_CHAR(SQLERRM(-6511)));
 END;`